# Web.Config Issues and Analyzers

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, web-config, membership-provider

I have a set of ASP.NET membership tables online with my hosting with godaddy.  I can run my site locally and connect to the online membership table fine and can create accounts etc..  So basically I got everything hooked to reference everything online.

But I get a 500 Internal Service error when I try to view the site.  I can't look at the event viewer cause godaddy does not allow that.  When I rename the web.config and refresh the site I can either get to the login or register page but when it try to save data it bombs.

So is their a good web.config analyzer that can tell me whats wrong? Cause it works locally referencing online db so it should work fine, right?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get a lot of information out of [trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y13fw6we%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) or add a logger like [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) and write log messages to a text file. That can tell you what is wrong.